# search result with ng-repeate that creates a "add" button (I want to not make this button if item already added)

Tags: angularjs

I think I need to do it with a filter somehow but I couldn't figure it out, the code below is what I created but I'm sure it is severely inefficient

```
$scope.isInList = function(ident){ 
  var answer = false;

  if($scope.List){ // stops it from firing before it has something to check against
      var length = $scope.Lister.list[number].ingr.length;
      for (var i=0; i < length; i++){
          if($scope.Lister.list[number].thing[i].id == ident){ var answer = true;}

      }
  }
  return answer;
};
```

in the view I just have a ng-hide, the function returns false if nothing is found..

```
ng-hide="isInList(ident)"
```

I see now that I can add Break; in the if when true to make it a little better but I'm still hoping for a sweeter angular way.

EDIT:

I just want to remove one object in the ng-repeat tho.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in List">item.name <button ng-click="addToAnotherList(item.id)">Add</em></li>
</ul>
```

can I make the filter just remove the  elem.?

And also can a filter check an array of variables?

I need the filter to check a undefined number of id-s from another list (to see that the item isn't already in that list)

now the ng-hide goes of for every result in a search, and the for loop checks every value in the list where I don't want duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will second the filter solution already provided by Mark but also offer you up one using ng-hide that I wouldn't recommend over the filter as it won't work on ie8 and isn't as optimized as the filter but is another option:

```
$scope.isInList = function(ident){ 

  return $scope.List && 
         $scope.List.thing.filter(function (item) { return (item.id == ident); }).length>0;
}
```

I wasn't 100% sure about the array names, but the general idea would work.

Comment: this was a bit to minfied for my experience lvl :) . Let me see if i get it... This checks if the list exists(true) and if item.id == ident  for the length of the list called thing ? am I right? it works I just want to understand it. ( you said the filter @Mark gave would work, but how does it check all the values of the list in the scope ? )

Comment: The filter i used is a plain old JavaScript function that will return an array of elements that match the condition.  My code was not optimized. Marks solution uses an angular filter which would remove the elements from the list in the first place so a hide is not needed.

Comment: So you would say a better solution would be a for loop inside the filter in @Mark 's solution that runs for every item in $scope.list replacing "Something" with item.id ? (or is it going over my head and will work as is?)

Comment: I would suggest you try marks first as it is the way I'd do it. The filter gets each object and removes those that font satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The better way would be to create a custom filter function for your list when you do `ng-repeat`

That way you do not have to deal with the `ng-hide` as it would be handled by the filter.

Without knowing your `<html/>`

I am assuming you have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in List"></li>
</ul>
```

You want to add in a `|filter:someFunction` to the `ng-repeat`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in List| filter: myFilterFunction"></li>
</ul>
```

```
$scope.myFilterFunction = function(item){ 
   if(item.SomeProperty === Something){
       return item;
   }
};
```

**[Simple example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/hfgqv/)**

Comment: Thank you that is close to what I need

I made an Edit to the post (for readability) for clarification.


I have been doing Angular for under a week so I haven't gotten my head around filters yet.